# ListView items not showing tap animation

Tags: android, listview

When I first created my ListView, tapping an item made a nice gradient animation, but it doesn't show anymore for some reason, and I've made too many recent changes to tell what broke it. Is there something in my code that's overriding the animation or breaking it? I'm pretty stumped :/

ACTIVITY XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.nwoodthorpe.busstop.AddActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select a Route"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:minHeight="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:typeface="normal"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="35dp"
        android:maxHeight="35dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        />

    <View android:background="#000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:id="@+id/div"/>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_below="@+id/div"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ACTIVITY JAVA FILE

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void onBackClick(View v){
        finish();
    }

    public void setButtonListeners(){
        ImageView backButton = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.back);
        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackClick(v);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        ArrayList<BusRoute> routes = UserValues.getInstance().stops;

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new AddListAdapter(this, 0, routes);

        // Link the data and our listview using the adapter.
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        setButtonListeners();
    }
}
```

ITEM XML FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="60dp"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:clickable="true"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/smallname"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="51A"
        android:textColor="@android:color/tab_indicator_text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:focusable="false"
        />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/longname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:focusable="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: ListView OnClick animation doesn't work if you set background color of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58399672/android-studio-listview-onclick-animation-doesnt-work-if-you-set-background-co)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the material design. Since android 5.0, google show us the [Material Design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html). The [ListView](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html#) is a part of it.
You can check if the device's version is android 5.0 or later. Also you can use some libraries like [this one](https://github.com/rey5137/material).
The animation is like [this](https://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/material-properties.html#material-properties-movement-of-material). Check the last section `Z-axis motion`.

You find the animation is gone because you set the background color. Try to remove the item's background.