# Android Studio: ListView OnClick animation doesn't work if you set background color of items

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-listview

In my project I've setted the background color of my items (composed of several elements inserted in a ConstraintLayout) inside a ListView but the default animation of click and long click disappears if the background color is not at least a little transparent. In fact, as transparency decreases, the effect of clicking on the elements is less and less evident. In a few words, color goes to hide the animation if isn't transparent. How to solve this problem and then bring selection animation to the foreground?

Same problem, still unresolved: [ListView items not showing tap animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36254196/listview-items-not-showing-tap-animation)

Comment: Convino, Do you have a separate `xml` for the ListView item. If yes, please attach that with the question.

Comment: Also, you can try setting `android:foreground="android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` for the list item's root view.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I've resolved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58403131/8998009

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RESOLVED!

You have to simply add `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"` in your ListView XML tag. In this way you can modify and customize the list item background and at the same time bring back the "selector" on top of the "z axis" of GUI. Yuhu!

Answer (score 1):

If you are giving a background coloraturas to the list items then you might be hiding the system press animations. in this case you can use the methods like OnItemLongClickListener() and itemClickListener () and add your custom animations to the view.

Comment: Actually, I would like changing the item background color while maintaining the default ListView tap animation. But currently I don't know how to do it.